# AES encryption value not parsing into function PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, encryption, aes

I am trying to get a word in a text box, encrypt it with AES and then put into a database. The problem I am having is I encrypt the word and when running `exit($encryptedword);` it shows the encrypted value of the word however when trying use a function to grab the encrypted word to insert it into the database it decrypts the bloody thing! My code is as follows:

```
include("resources/sec/AES.class.php");
include("resources/sec/AES.encrypt.php");


$data = $word;
$encryptedword = $aes->encrypt($data);

function generateCode($encryptedword, $refid) {

    exit ($encryptedword);

}
```

To sum it up, before I start that function it produces the encrypted value, once the variable is used in the function and is called or in this case printed in an exit to test it decrypts it and shows the non-encrypted password...

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show us your **function** call also... are you sure you aren't passing `$data` or `$word` to it by mistake?

Comment: @FDL the call of the variable to test is the exit($encryptedword)?

Comment: Where are you using `generateCode()`? It's not actually being triggered in the above code, show us where you use it

Comment: What does `var_dump($data, $encryptedword = $aes->encrypt($data));` give?

Comment: And the code of `AES.class.php` and `AES.encrypt.php` is missing. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue, when calling the function to be used I did not include the variable I needed! *Doh!*

so by using

```
$code = generateCode($encryptedword, $_POST['word'], $_POST['refnumber']);
echo $code;
```

This worked!